# Can't publish on jitpack

Tags: android, gradle, jitpack

I have a problem with publishing multi-flavor [library](https://github.com/yzheka/Busybox) to jitpack.
The log says that build success but the status is error

[image]

I've followed instructions on jitpack site but their sample uses old gradle version and it did not work with gradle 4.4

Here is the log:

```
Build starting...
Start: Fri Apr 20 07:35:56 UTC 2018
Git:
1.28.1-1-g932f4d8
commit 932f4d88e13b1c8c52b4dbae8c203e7d52a0eadf
Author: yzheka 
Date:   Fri Apr 20 10:34:49 2018 +0300

    jitpack config


Run gradle build
Gradle build script
Found gradle version: 4.4.
Using gradle wrapper
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
..............................................................................................
Unzipping /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1/gradle-4.4-all.zip to /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1
Set executable permissions for: /home/jitpack/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-all/9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1/gradle-4.4/bin/gradle

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.14.15-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 amd64

0m4.923s
Getting a list of gradle tasks
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.yzheka -Pversion=-1.28.1-g932f4d8-1 -xtest -xlint install
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
:clean
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:busybox:clean UP-TO-DATE
:busybox:install

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
EXIT_CODE=0
2018-04-20T07:36:32.030445377Z
Exit code: 0
No build artifacts found
```

Comment: Seems like the build can't find any artifacts (_No build artifacts found_). Can you share your Gradle configuration?

Comment: @wasyl You can find github repo in link above

Comment: ```
:clean
:app:clean UP-TO-DATE
:busybox:clean UP-TO-DATE
:busybox:install
```
looks like there is no `assemble` triggered

Comment: @quentin-klein Do you know how to make jitpack to trigger assemble process?

Comment: @MykhailoYuzheka you would add in your `busybox/build.gradle`: `afterEvaluate { project.tasks.findByName('install').dependsOn('assemble') }`. `afterEvaluate` might not be needed in fact, but it probably won't hurt

Comment: @wasyl This is not helped. Now I can see that all assemble tasks executed build successfull but it still marked as error in kitpack and still no artifacts found https://jitpack.io/com/github/yzheka/Busybox/1.28.1/build.log

Comment: @tynn Yes, I've added

`apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'`

Comment: Not what I was stating: First apply `com.android.library` and after `com.github.dcendents.android-maven`.

Comment: @tynn Still the same.

Comment: The `assemble` task is not used for libraries, it's the `bundle` task instead. So you can remove `project.tasks.findByName('install').dependsOn('assemble')` and trust the plugins to setup the graph properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In jitpack log you can see why jitpack can't publish your library**. Just delete some part of your code because of jitpack error.

> Cannot get the value of write-only property 'publishNonDefault' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

```
if( android.publishNonDefault && variant.name == android.defaultPublishConfig ) {
                def bundleTask = tasks["bundle${name.capitalize()}"]
                artifacts {
                    archives(bundleTask.archivePath) {
                        classifier null
                        builtBy bundleTask
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then jitpack do not show the error when publishing your library. Works like a charm. To publish your library just realese once again then publish your libary.

Answer (score 0):

This way is worked for me:

Add these line in the `Module gradle` after `dependencies` part :

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = 'com.github.yourgitid' //your git id
                artifactId = 'Myket-Intent' //your-repository
                version = '0.1.15' // same as Tag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

after that you can see:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 41s
123 actionable tasks: 120 executed, 3 up-to-date
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: com.github.Mori-hub:Myket-Intent:0.1.15
2022-01-22T09:38:10.889110195Z
Exit code: 0

Build artifacts:
com.github.Mori-hub:Myket-Intent:0.1.15
```

Comment: All steps are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70811778/12272687